# ansible динамическая инвентаризация в домене

Tags: windows, ansible

Есть домен с кучей компьютеров и я хочу автоматически добавлять их в файл инвентаризации Ansible. К примеру это можно было бы осуществить через групповые политики, но я не нашел способа это сделать. Подскажите, если вы решали данную задачу.

Comment: Этот файл будет правиться руками или он полностью генерённый?

Comment: Уже читали? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html